# Spark giving logging error even after finding two libraries

Tags: java, apache-spark

Even though it is finding two logging libraries and then giving warning about that. Later it is saying `Logging$` is not find.

See the error message below. Not sure what I was doing wrong here.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/msuri/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/0.9.25/logback-classic-0.9.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/msuri/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.633 sec <<< FAILURE!
Exception in thread "delete Spark temp dirs" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.Logging$
        at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.initializeIfNecessary(Logging.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.log(Utils.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logError(Logging.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logError(Utils.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1623)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anon$4.run(Utils.scala:177)
```

Here is a part of the dependency tree:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ps-primary-spark ---
[INFO] com.playspan:ps-primary-spark:jar:1.x-CASSANDRA
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:jar:1.3.1:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill_2.10:jar:0.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.5.0:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.2.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.2.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.6.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.2.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.6.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.2.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.6.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.2.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.6.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.2.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.6.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.2.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.6.0)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.2.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.10:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.10:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.10:jar:1.3.1:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.7.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile - version managed from 1.2; scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.4.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.6.0)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0:provided - version managed from 14.0.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0:compile - version managed from 14.0.1; scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:provided
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - version managed from 1.6.4; scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- (org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.1.6:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.2.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.4.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- (commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.2:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-remote_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-actor_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (io.netty:netty:jar:3.8.0.Final:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.spark-project.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0-spark:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths:jar:1.2.2a:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-slf4j_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.spark-project.akka:akka-actor_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - version managed from 1.7.5; scope managed from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.10:jar:3.2.10:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.10.4)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:jar:3.2.10:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.10.4)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:jar:3.2.10:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.10.4)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.6:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.scala-lang:scalap:jar:2.10.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.10.4)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.1:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.4.4)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.mesos:mesos:jar:shaded-protobuf:0.21.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; scope managed from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.0:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; scope managed from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.0:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.2:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.3.1)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; scope managed from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.0:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; scope managed from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:jar:2.4.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.4:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.4:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.4.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.6:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:provided - omitted for conflict with 1.3.9)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.tachyonproject:tachyon-client:jar:0.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tachyonproject:tachyon:jar:0.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - version managed from 1.7.2; scope managed from provided; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.2:provided - omitted for conflict with 1.7.10)
[INFO] |  |     +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:provided - version managed from 2.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 3.3.2)
[INFO] |  |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.4.4)
[INFO] |  +- org.spark-project:pyrolite:jar:2.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.8.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- (org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:compile - scope updated from provided; omitted for duplicate)
```

Comment: Did you try excluding one of the logging libraries from the classpath to see if that would make a difference?

Comment: We tried excluding the dependencies but it didn't work:    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

Comment: Did you set the spark-core dependency as a scope of provided? Usually spark dependencies are under provided scope.

Comment: I tried after setting the spark-core dependency as  scope provided but still getting the same error. <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

Comment: How are you running the test? Are you running a Maven clean and compile?

 Just out of curiosity, if you skipped tests would you be able to compile and run your project?

Comment: Yes, I am running the tests as mvn test -Dtest=<classname> and it fails with the exception  as Exception in thread "delete Spark temp dirs" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.Logging$. When I use it in other modules and add this as dependency , then also it fails.

Comment: Can you give the classpath tree output in the question using the Maven dependency plugin? If you don't know how to use the plugin here is a official link https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/. Something in the classpath is causing this issue but I don't know until I can see the tree output.

Comment: Run this command for classpath output: mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
and put it in the question and not in a comment. Please delete your other comments that contain the file paths. We might need to set up a chat room as we are starting to accumulate a lot of comments.

Comment: Can you remove the slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5 dependency? Spark core for 1.3.1 depends on 1.7.10. I also don't know why this was in the tree output: `+- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile` but it should have been version 1.7.10.

Comment: This solved my problem. Can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5 dependency as Spark core for 1.3.1 depends on 1.7.10 for slf4j-log4j12.

I also don't know why this was in the tree output: +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile but it should have been version 1.7.10.